# New Battery Problem iPhone 7

Tags: battery, charging

I’ve decided to change my Battery all of the sudden while I was on a tour in an another country so I went to a Apple certified shop , they told me to charge my iPhone for 6 hours without interruption and then use my phone to drain it back to 0 then charge it again for 6 hours.

I complied and charged it for 7 hours but when I used it until 80 percent my phone died and showed me the black screen with the white Apple icon then demanded I charge it again from scratch.

I thought it’s part of the system and did it again but to no avail - it still dies at any percentage beyond 50% and demands I recharge again from 0.

I tried changing some settings as the Apple support site recommends but nothing changed, any suggestions before I get it inspected again?

EDIT: actually I found something new , My iPhone charges properly only when it reaches 22 percent correctly but after it surpasses that it will be my choice...

Either charge it full and the power dies at 80 percent(that means using then 22 percent that charged perfectly)

Or I unplug it after the 22 percent (even 24%) but it will show no reduction in the battery percentage but it will die eventually(After using 22% secretly I think) So any ideas guys?

Comment: Have you tried going back to the store that did the work?

Comment: Sounds like the replacement battery might be faulty. Since they are an authorised service provider you should get another replacement for free (under warranty) at the same or any other authorised service provider without issue.

Comment: I know but I just wanna check if the problem could be from the software since if I charge it less than 50 it won’t die on me that’s why if I could solve it here then that’s the best …